# Create not going forward

Tags: ros, create-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have a weird one. I have been searching for a bit to try and find the answer to this, but there doesn't seem to  be anything on it here.

Basically, I have installed Turtlebot on Ubuntu 11.04, I have the standard netbook setup, diamondback.
I have also used my desktop computer running Ubuntu 10.04, and installed it on a Debian device.
In all three cases, the Create will not go forward, it will only turn left, right and backwards.

Is there some possibility that a flag is set? Something that doesn't allow it to go forward?

I would really appreciate your help on this. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11129/create-not-going-forward/) by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2011-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-09-13**:
Hi. I am using the keyboard. I used "rostopic echo turtlebot_node/cmd_vel". I am getting a linear vel of 0.5 when pressing forward, but still no signs of life.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-06**:
the cmd_vel is in the turtlebot_node namespace. You need to rostopic echo turtlebot_node/cmd_vel to see the commands. what are you using to command the robot to go forward? joystick, keyboard?

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-09-06**:
I am commanding it to go forward, but nothing more than the following appears.

rostopic echo cmd_vel WARNING: topic [/cmd_vel] does not appear to be published yet

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-09-06**:
Could you post the output from `rostopic echo cmd_vel` for a time when you're commanding it to go forward, but it isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like the bumper might be depressed.  Can you look in the diagnostics in the dashboard about whether the bumper is pressed.  There's also a parameter to allow driving even when the bumper is pressed.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-12-06**:
Was the case of a depressed bumper.

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-09-15**:
Hi, there is a starter program that is on the Command Module that makes the robot just bump and drive. This goes forward without problem. Also, when I was performing the Calibration part of the Turtlebot setup, it was going forwards.

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-09-13**:
Hi, can I ask how do you apply these parameters when using the turtlebot_bringup? Thanks.

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-09-09**:
Similarly, it could be the wheeldrop sensors.  The parameter in question is `~stop_motors_on_bump`.  It was missing from the docs; I've just added it (along with some other missing params): http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node#Parameters.